# Play kills itself with "Uncaught error from thread" without exception stack

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, akka, playframework-2.5

I have this bizarre behaviour of my Play 2.5.14 application - it randomly crashes without displaying a full error stack. It started with crashing with the following line in the log:

```
2017-04-21 17:13:32,345 [ERROR] from akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-27 - Uncaught error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-39] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
```

So I included the following setting in the `application.conf`:

```
akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error = off
```

Now it is crashing with the error

```
2017-04-24 00:26:33,307 [ERROR] from akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-46 - Uncaught fatal error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-40] shutting down ActorSystem [application]
```

There's literally nothing else pointing to the reason. Sometimes the app runs for several days without crash and sometimes just a few minutes. How can I find the reason? Any way to enable more consistent logging?

Comment: Try enabling AKKA logs in your [logback.xml](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SettingsLogger#Akka-logging-configuration) It might help you.

Comment: @Sivakumar I did, had no effect.

Comment: log must work, you will not resolve it without logging enabled.

Comment: @AndriyKuba Logging does work normally, Sivakumar was talking about additional AKKA logging enabled in logback.xml which I did and it didn't produce anything useful appart from some dead letters that are unrelated to this problem.

Comment: But it must be something, log must print that "Uncaught error", like `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread`,  `java.lang.StackOverflowError at java.util.regex.Pattern`, `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`

Comment: for example, look at the similar uncaught error in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120369/uncaught-error-from-default-dispatcher-causes-fatal-error-with-javatestkit. 

Can you add more from the log?

Comment: @AndriyKuba There is literally nothing besides what I posted in my question. No error stacktrace in the log, which is the whole point of this question.

Comment: @Caballero Do you have any clue about what may be causing this? Have you done any recent upgrade of Play? Any change in actor code that uses any new library? Without more info, I would try to check if this is nothing related to an OOM or any jar missing that may cause a ClassNotFoundException... Or even downgrade to an older Play version (ex 2.5.4) to check if is some problem in the framework itself

Comment: @Salem I have tried previous two Play versions with no luck. No idea what is causing this. The point of a framework especially one built on AKKA is to handle uncaught errors, provide resilience and prevent a complete crash of the whole application which makes this look like some major bug with the framework itself.

Comment: @Caballero Have you managed to find a solution? I'm facing same problem

Comment: @Michał Unfortunately no, I'm pretty sure this is a bug in Play or even Akka. I've managed to find and fix the specific cause in my situation - an interface was missing implementation, but your case will of course be different.

Comment: @Caballero Thank you, I'll try to figure it out.